# 2 simultaneous VPNs to 2 different nodes

Tags: vpn, ipsec

I am planning to setup Ipsec tunnels between a single server (server1) and two security gateways (seg1 and seg2).The setup should be like this:

```
server1 -----ipsec tunnel1-------->seg1

server1 -----ipsec tunnel2-------->seg2
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: What did your Google searching tell you?

Comment: Im not able to find anything.

Comment: I found 3 questions on this very site. "Try Harder"tm.

Comment: Any Update on my query ?